# Programmatically Recall iOS push notification alert after deny option selection is possible?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Suppose if the User selected **Don't Allow** option unfortunately in push notification, then is there any way to programmatically alert the user with the same message instead of redirecting it to settings page. Is this possible if yes, please let me know how to make it work.

Comment: Once the user has responded to the initial iOS prompt, you cannot prompt then again. They can only change the settings in the settings app.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible as stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1):

> The first time that your app launches and calls the
>   requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler: method, the system
>   prompts the user to grant or deny the requested interactions. Because
>   the system saves the user’s response, calls to this method during
>   subsequent launches do not prompt the user again.